# DateTime shows the date as 01/01/0001

Tags: c#, datetime

Sorry if this seems as a stupid question, but I cannot find an answer anywhere and I am a bit of a newbie. DateTime shows to be what I surmised as the Min Date. For instance:

```
DateTime updatedDate = new DateTime();
outItem.AddDate = updatedDate.ToLongDateString();
```

The output comes out to January 01, 0001. I've tried many variations of this with similar results. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10):

It depends on what you mean by "wrong". `new DateTime()` does indeed have the same value as `DateTime.MinValue`. If you want the *current* time, you should use:

```
DateTime updatedDate = DateTime.Now;
```

or

```
DateTime updatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

(The first gives you the *local* time, the second gives you the *universal* time. `DateTime` is [somewhat messed up](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html) when it comes to the local/universal divide.)

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking to get the current date, use `DateTime.Now`.  You're creating a new instance of the date class, and the min value is its default value.

```
DateTime updatedDate = DateTime.Now;
outItem.AddDate = updatedDate.ToLongDateString();
```

EDIT: Actually, you can shorten your code by just doing this:

```
outItem.AddDate = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
```

Answer (score 3):

Jon Skeet says correct, and I have some to add.

The "wrong" depends on what time you want to get.

The **DateTime** is a **struct**, and the the default contructor of a **struct**

always initializes all fields to their zero for numeric type and null

for reference type.

so if you want to get the current local date and time, you can call static property DateTime.Now.

```
   var curDateTime = DateTime.Now;
```

if you want to get UTC time.

```
   var utcDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Note: the DateTime.UtcNow get the current date and time, but instead of using local time zone, it uses UTC time instead.

You can reference the link as below.

http://blackrabbitcoder.net/archive/2010/11/18/c.net-little-wonders-datetime-is-packed-with-goodies.aspx